# Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{211}{307}\right)$ calculation

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, legendre-symbol

Are my calculation correct?

$$\left(\frac{211}{307}\right)=-\left(\frac{307}{211}\right)=-\left(\frac{159}{211}\right)=-\left(\frac{53}{211}\right)-\left(\frac{3}{211}\right)=-\left(\frac{211}{53}\right)\times-\left(\frac{211}{3}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{53}\right)\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$$ (since 2 negatives cancel out).

Then knowing the facts that $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=1^{(3-1)/2}=1$ and $53 \equiv +-3 \pmod{8}\Rightarrow \left(\frac{-1}{53}\right)=-1$

Put everything together to get $-1$?

Comment: I wouldn't use $-a-b$ to mean $(-a)(-b)$. I'd put $(-1)$ in place of the minus signs just for clarity.

Comment: And where does $159$ come from?

Comment: It should be $-\left(\frac{307}{211}\right)=-\left(\frac{96}{211}\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) and the [properties of the Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol#Properties_of_the_Legendre_symbol):

$$\left(\frac{211}{307}\right)=-\left(\frac{307}{211}\right)=-\left(\frac{96}{211}\right)=-\left(\frac{2}{211}\right)^5\left(\frac{3}{211}\right)$$

$211\equiv 3\pmod{8}$ and $211\equiv 7\pmod{12}$, so by [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.C2.B12_and_the_second_supplement) $$=-(-1)^5(-1)=-1$$

---

As has been said on the Wikipedia page I linked, $\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)=1\iff p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{12}$.

Proof: If $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, then $\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)=1\iff p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, so $p\equiv 1\pmod{12}$ (see [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)).

If $p\equiv -1\pmod{4}$, then $\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)=-\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)=1\iff p\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, so $p\equiv -1\pmod{12}$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I know where primes mod4 (for -1) and primes mod8 (for 2's) come from. But how do you conclude the last line $(\frac{3}{211})$? Why is it mod 12?

Comment: @HeavyWeight I've edited the answer.